# Futures data on Quantopian

Tags: futures

I'm new to Quantopian and I'm not sure why I can't seem to see data for the e-mini futures ('ES') past around November, 2018.  Have futures been discontinued?

Comment: This question belongs on the Quantopian web site. Although there are some Quantopian users here on quant.stackexchange, it is not the best place to ask this question.